# Filter by a value in two columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My table looks like this

| Team | Language | People |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Team A | English | 3 |
| Team B | English | 4 |
| Team B | Spanish | 3 |
| Team Spanish | Spanish | 4 |
| Team C | Portuguese | 4 |

If you notice, `Team B` handles English and Spanish and there's also a `Team Spanish`.

I want to combine `Team Spanish` with `Team B - Spanish`, so it only shows one row with the sum of 7 people.

My expected result:

| Team | Language | People |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Team Spanish | Spanish | 7 |

My workaround is to create an extra column, combine the `Team` column with the `Language` column and then sum the results

```
SUMIF(people, aux_col IN ('team B - Spanish', 'Team Spanish - Spanish')) AS new_people_count
```

Never mind the last code, it's just pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your query which has a condition changes all Team B-Spanish to Team Spanish I also added the count function that added (sum()) of people and produced the Expected output:

```
WITH Sample AS
 (SELECT 'Team A' as Team, "English" as Language, 3 as People UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Team B', "English", 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Team B', "Spanish", 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Team Spanish', "Spanish", 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Team C', "Portuguese", 4)

SELECT Language, CASE
WHEN CONCAT(Team, '-', Language) = 'Team B-Spanish' THEN 'Team Spanish'
ELSE Team
END AS Team,
SUM (People) as People
From Sample where Language = "Spanish" GROUP BY Team, Language
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

i made my calculation using google sheet.
I think you must complete your goal in two steps:
First step
Create a table like your original table.
This is the original table in google sheet
[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OAkm.png).
In the new table write the headers and the under the TEAM column write this formula
=if (B3<>"Spanish";A3;"Team Spanish")
copy this formula in rows from 4 to 7.
Under the column LANGUAGE and PEOPLE copy the exact value of the original table
example for LANGUAGE column write =B3 and copy from this formula in rows from 4 to 7.
example for PEOPLE column write =C3 and copy from this formula in rows from 4 to 7.
At the end you will have this table:
[Table step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Uif.png)

finally you have to pivot the previous table.
in the rows put TEAM and LANGUAGE.
Don't pu anything in column
SUM of PEOPLE.
And here you have your final table
[Final Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQoxM.png)

Let me know if that is what you wanted to do.
bye

Comment: hi, unfortunately I'm organizing my data in bigquery, not in Google Sheets

Answer (score 0):

I was overcomplicating my idea... This code solves the issue

```
CASE
WHEN CONCAT(team, '-', language) = 'Team B-Spanish' THEN 'Team Spanish'
ELSE team
END AS team,
```

Answer (score 0):

in SQL you can run a query like this:

select case when Language="Spanish" then "Team Spanish" else Team end as Team,
Language, sum(People)
from myTable
group by Team, Language

Let me know if this can be a solution for you.